# Active model JSON Serialization of a rails inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have 3 models Persona, Assertion and class P2c is inherited from class Assertion

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  # create_table "personas", :force => true do |t|
  #  t.text     "name",        :null => false
  #  t.text     "description"
  #  t.datetime "last_change", :null => false
  # end
    has_many :p2cs
end

class Assertion < ActiveRecord::Base
# create table "assertions", :primary_key => "id", :force => true do |t|
#    t.text "rationale",
# end
end

class P2c < Assertion
#create_table "p2cs", :primary_key => "assertion_ptr_id", :force => true do |t|
#  t.integer "persona_id",         :null => false
# end
    belongs_to :persona, :class_name => "Persona", :foreign_key => "persona_id"
end
```

I need help to write the serialization classes using gem active_model_serializers

Comment: Serialize to what format?  JSON and YAML are already baked in...

Comment: more context is required. I just saw that you use inheritance but not STI : is that part of your problem ?

Comment: Hi Pierre, please include some kind of specs (if you don't know Test::Unit or RSpec it can be just readable specs, as long as we can undertand the desired outcome).

Comment: Hi Franck, my answer is in 409 railscasts but I need help for the case of inherited classes which is not considered in this railscasts

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. But I guess you had issue with your STI. STI and polymorphism are not explained in the RailsCast 409, but they talk about it in the documentation.

The key is that you have to specify the serializer.
Lets say I have a

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base 
class Child < Parent
```

I would have the following show/index actions:

```
def index
  render json: children, each_serializer: ParentSerializer
end

def show
  render json: child, serializer: ParentSerializer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but i assume you want to include p2cs in your personnae. `as_json` is the preferred way to implement default JSON serialization in rails

```
class Personna < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json( options={} )
    super( {include: [:p2cs]}.merge options )
  end
end
```

If your problem is to implement different behavior for `P2c` and `Assertion`, just implement `as_json` as needed in each of the classes.

**note** you may find that blog post about json serialization interesting, because it clarifies the difference between `as_json` and `to_json` : http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/

the idea is that we need to split json serialization into two steps : build a ruby hash of attributes (as_json), and then serialize it (to_json). This way inheritance and overloading are easier, because we can just process a ruby hash.